# How do I force the debugged app to open in a secondary monitor with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I debug an application in VS2010 I want it to open in my secondary monitor, but it always  opens in the primary monitor. How do I force it to open in the secondary monitor?

I have read elsewhere on SO that I need to move the app to the secondary window and close it (not shift-F5) and it will open there the next time. This doesn't work.

Comment: does setting the second monitor as the primary display solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the second monitor as the primary display.

The application will be launched in this display.

The only drawback is that this setting is global and will change, by default, the taskbar position, powerpoint presentation, etc.

Comment: Unless someone comes up with a good VS based solution, I'll accept this answer in a couple of days. I want to leave it open until then just in case.

Comment: this **is** a solution, even with a real limitation. But this works. Why do you assert this is not a real solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually another solution:
put some code in the application,
that only runs when debugging, to
move the window to the second
monitor when it launches.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [Steve B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588868/steve-b) in the comments for this. Set the secondary monitor to be your primary monitor (via display properties/settings) does the trick. The app now launches in the "other" monitor

Answer (score 0):

For VS2017, simply do this:
1. select your Visual Studio main window
2. hover mouse over the monitor where you want the app to run
3. Press  to run

App starts wherever mouse was hovering.